# Dealing with char ** argv

Tags: c++, arrays, command-line, pointers, arguments

How do I assign a sequence of character strings to a char ** argv variable in a program? Its a command line argument. I'm currently trying to convert an .exe app to a dll.

For example:

{ "string1", "string2", "string3" } --- > char ** argv variable

My problem is somehow realted to this:
 [How does an array of pointers to pointers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015944/how-does-an-array-of-pointers-to-pointers-work/1015970#1015970) but I can't get it to work using the snippet shown there. Help!

Comment: Are you trying to assign the three command-line arguments to three separate char* variables in your program, or are you trying to assign three variables into a char** you have declared yourself?

Comment: I'm trying to assign 3 strings to the char** I have declared. I might also reassigned a different sequence of strings on the later part of the program. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to modify the passed-in parameters?

Answer (score 8):

`const char* argv[] = {"string1", "string2", "string3", 0};`

If the arguments aren't compile time constants I would do something like:

```
std::vector<const char*> arguments;
arguments.push_back(somePointer);
arguments.push_back(someOtherPointer);
arguments.push_back(0);
const char** argv = &arguments[0];
```

**EDIT:** Using PaxDiablos information that an `argv`-array should be null terminated.

Comment: @Andreas, if it's a true argv (as in what main expects), it should have a fourth pointer set to NULL. That may not, however, be part of the requirements for this situation.

Comment: That's better, deleting mine since it adds nothing new now (and because it uses malloc - ugh!).

Comment: I can't remember how they're stored internally, but in this example would std::vector<std::string> be usable?

Comment: @John No, there's no way to directly pass a `std::vector<std::string>` to a function expecting a `char**`.

Answer (score 0):

what about [getopt](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getopt.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Note that Andreas Brincks answer is really what you want to do, where vector does all the heavy lifting of allocation and provides exception safety. I strongly suggest that you look into changing whatever reason there is for not being able to use vector. But if you really really cannot do so, I guess you could do something along the lines of the below code:

```
int numArgs = YOUR_NUMBER_HERE;

char **myArgv = new char*[numArgs+1];

for (int i=0; i<numArgs; ++i) {
    myArgv[i] = new char[at least size of your argument + 1];
    strncpy(myArgv[i], whereever your string is, buffer size);
    myArgv[buffer size] = '\0';
}
myArgv[numArgs] = NULL;


// use myArgv here


// now you need to manually free the allocated memory
for (int i=0; i<numArgs; ++i) {
    delete [] myArgv[i];
}
delete [] myArgv;
```