# Assigning array to pointer confusion

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variable-assignment

I was confused by a line of code I found in a tutorial on C. Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   ...
   char **inputs = argv+1; // This is the confusing line
   ...
   return 0;
}
```

I can't understand how can you assign an array to a pointer like that. I would be glad if someone could clarify this for me. Thanks ahead!

Comment: there are no arrays in this example. is `inputs = &argv[1]` less confusing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confusing pointers in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108898/confusing-pointers-in-c)

Comment: `argv` is an array of pointers and `argv` represents the address of the  `*argv[0]` so I think you can absolutely assign it like that.

Comment: But doesn't it assign just argv[1] instead of the whole argv[] starting with argv[1]?

Comment: No, `argv[1]` would be equivalent to `*(argv+1)`, not equivalent to `argv+1`. In other words, `argv+1` is a pointer to `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you execute a program like this

> C:\Temp>myprog.exe hello world

the operating system takes these strings and puts them together, in an array of null-terminating strings:

```
{ "myprog.exe", "hello", "world", NULL }
```

Then it calls `main()` and passes it the number of strings (3) as `argc` and a pointer to the first string in this array. this pointer is calles `argv`, and is of type `char**` (`char* argv[]` is just a syntactic convenience, semantically equivalent inside function signatures)

but you want `inputs` to hold only the string "hello" and "world", so you takes this pointer, `argc`, and point to the next element - add one to it:

```
char **inputs = argv+1;
```

now `inputs` points toward `{ "hello", "world", NULL }` .

Answer (score 2):

`argv` is an array pointers to strings, last pointer is null. 
Suppose your executable name is `exe` and you run it like:

```
$ exe fist second
```

then `argv` is:

```
                     +----------+ 
             argv---►| "exe"    | 
                     +----------+ 
         argv + 1---►| "first"  | 
                     +----------+ 
         argv + 2---►| "second" | 
                     +----------+      
         argv + 3---►|  null    |      
                     +----------+      

    * Notice last is null.
```

So `char** input = argv + 1` points to "first" string that is first input argument.

if your prints `argv[0]` with `%s` output will be `"exe"` that is your executable name and if you prints `input[0]` with `%s` output will be `"fisrt"` string.

**Note:** even if you don't pass any argument `intput` will point to NULL (valid address).
(purpose of this is to point to input arguments strings, or say skip program name `"exe"`)

My following code example, and its set of outputs will help you to understand.
**code.c:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char** input = argv + 1;
    while(*input) /* run untill input-->null */
        printf("%s \n", *input++);
    return 1;
}
```

**outputs:**

```
~$ gcc code.c  -Wall  -pedantic  -o exe 
~$ ./exe 
~$ ./exe first
first 
~$ ./exe first second
first 
second
```

Answer (score 0):

Array Name is a constant pointer to the first element of array

MORE:-
http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/showthread.php?t=56256

Comment: not true, and also irrelevant here: the are *no* arrays in this code.

Comment: the question is "how can you assign an array to a pointer" and that is the possible explanation, ie, if array name is a constant pointer so it can be assign to a pointer, ELAZAR

Comment: It is an explanation, but an accurate one. and there are no array here, so it's also irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays used in function arguments are always converted to pointers.

So `char *argv[]` is the same as `char **argv`.

`argv[0]` contains the program name (or the name used to invoke the program, in the case of a multiply-linked file), so `argv+1` is just the program's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is not an array in this context; it is a pointer value.  In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are equivalent to `T *a`; in all three declare `a` as a pointer to `T`.

However, it would still be possible to make the assignment even if `argv` were an array.  Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that

```
char *argv[]
```

Is an array of pointers. An array declaration, is a pointer itself, argv is a pointer. Since here we have an array of pointers, argv is a pointer to a pointer, just like char **inputs, thus

```
char **inputs = argv+1;
```

Is just saying inputs is equal to the pointer argv plus one and since argv+1 is also a pointer, then you have a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: If someone rates my answer negatively, please explain why.  Thank you.

Comment: It wasn't me, but there are some infelicities in your explanation. An array declaration is not a pointer, but it is implicitly converted to a pointer when used in a function argument.