# Passing char * vs char ** as parameters to a function in C

Tags: c, char, parameter-passing

I've read several discussions of passing char * in C.

[stackoverflow: passing-an-array-of-strings-as-parameter-to-a-function-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486075/passing-an-array-of-strings-as-parameter-to-a-function-in-c#486095)
[stackoverflow: how-does-an-array-of-pointers-to-pointers-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015944/how-does-an-array-of-pointers-to-pointers-work/1015970#1015970)
[stackoverflow: whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/484900#484900)
[drexel.edu: Character arrays](http://einstein.drexel.edu/courses/Comp_Phys/General/C_basics/#character)

Many of them include discussions of arrays, but I want to stay away from that.

I'm writing a sample program to teach myself about the passing of `char *` and `char **` in C.   This is an exercise in passing char *, without using (pointers to) arrays. Also no concerns for execution efficiency.  :-)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void get_args_works(int, char **, char **);
void get_args_broken(int, char **, char *);
char *get_string(int, char **);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *string_works;
  char *string_broken;

  get_args_works(argc, argv, &string_works);
  get_args_broken(argc, argv, string_broken);

  printf("in main string_works (%p) = %s\n",string_works,string_works);
  free(string_works);

  printf("in main string_broken (%p) = %s\n",string_broken,string_broken);
  free(string_broken);
}

void get_args_works(int argc, char **argv, char **string)
{
    *string = get_string(argc, argv);
    printf("in get_args_works %p string %s\n",*string,*string);
}

void get_args_broken(int argc, char **argv, char *string)
{
  string = get_string(argc, argv);
  printf("in get_args_broken %p string %s\n",string,string);
}

char * get_string(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;
  char *string;
  string = malloc(40);

  // placeholder in case -s switch not found below
  strcpy(string,"-s switch not found below");

  for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
      if(argv[i][0] == '-')
        {
          switch(argv[i][1])
            {
            case 's':
              // release above malloc(40) for "-s switch not found below"
              free(string);
              // make room for storing variable
              string = malloc(strlen(argv[++i]) + 1);
              // the argv just after -s
              strcpy (string,argv[i]);
              break;
            }
        }
    }
  return string;
}
```

You can also view the [same code on github](https://github.com/thunderrabbit/sea-review/blob/327bcda133ada7a124be423400e72fef997e5e5d/stackoverflow.c)

The above code is somewhat self documenting.  `main()` declares two char * variables, and passes them as parameters to their respective `get_args()` functions.

Each `get_args()` function calls `char * get_string(int, char **)`, using the exact same call (but different way to collect the return value).

`get_string()` works fine; it does a `malloc()` and returns the pointer back to the calling function.  That code works, and each `get_args()` function receives the return value as I expect.

But then, when the get_args() functions return to `main()`, why does the dereferenced pointer value get back to main (from `get_args_works()`, but not the pointer's value (from `get_args_broken()`)?

(i.e. I can see that if I dereference the pointer (`&string_works`) when sending as a parameter, it works.  But why?  Isn't `char * string_broken` already a pointer?  Why does it need the "extra" dereference when sending as a parameter?)

I'm hoping for a winning answer that explains how you (yes, you) conceptualize sending char * as a parameter vs receiving it as the function's return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int get_args_broken(int argc, char **argv, char *string)
{
  string = get_string(argc, argv);
  printf("in get_args_broken %p string %s\n",string,string);
}
```

You're only modifying the `string` local (automatic) variable.  That's not visible to the caller in any way.  Note that this means you're freeing a wild pointer in main.

It's wrong for the same reason:

```
int get_sum(int sum, int a, int b)
{
  sum = a + b;
}
```

is; the parameter is *copied* by value.  Also, you're not returning an int (as you declared you would).

```
int get_args_works(int argc, char **argv, char **string)
{
    *string = get_string(argc, argv);
    printf("in get_args_works %p string %s\n",*string,*string);
}
```

is correct (except the missing return).  You're not modifying `string`, which would be pointless.  You're modifying the object *at* the location in `string`, which in this case is a `char *`.

EDIT: You would need to triple * the argv if there was a function calling main, and you wanted to set that function's variable to a different char **.  E.G.

```
void trip_main(int *argc, char ***argv)
{
  *argc = 10; 
  *argv = malloc(*argc * sizeof(char *));
}

void caller()
{
  char **argv;
  int argc;
  trip_main(&argc, &argv);
}
```

Comment: hmmm.  I guess that may be a good simple way to understand it.  It doesn't talk about char * in any way.

but then why don't we need to triple * the argv?  hmmmm.

Comment: OMG !!!  How did I miss the invalid return type? ?  I've been composing this question for *days*...!!!!  d'oh!!!!

Comment: @ThunderRabbit: time to learn how to turn on more warnings from your compiler, or get a better compiler.  If your compiler does not complain about functions declared to return a value that return without returning a value, it is ... well, not precisely broken, but not being as helpful as it should be.  Compiler warnings are your friend - listen to it speak, and make sure it is verbose.  With GCC, a good starting point is '-Wall'; I usually use '-Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition' (the last because I work on archaic code).  '-Wshadow' is good too...

Comment: Thanks, Jon; I am using gcc, so I'll be sure to check out the -W options.

Answer (score 1):

One of the needs to use Pointer to a pointer (here `get_args_works()`) is to modify (or return) more than on variable from a function, as in C it's not possible to return more than one variable.

`get_args_works()` works 'coz, you are passing pointer to a pointer & a reference to it is there in your `main()`.

But in `get_args_broken()` you are passing just a pointer. Nothing wrong here, now you do `malloc()` & return back the memory allocated string to `get_args_broken()`, still nothing wrong here. But now, this mem allocated string is local & `main()` does not have a reference to this var. So when you dereference `char *string_broken;` in main() it might cause undefined behavior.

Hope this's clear.